# Link opens 404 error page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm having a problem with a WordPress link. I'm using php to link to my subpage called `page-projekti.php` with the following code:

```
<?php echo site_url('/projekti/'); ?>
```

When I click the link, it opens up a 404 page, which says:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

The link used to work just fine before I reinstalled WordPress due to some issues I had. Now it just displays this page everytime I click on it.

Did I change something important by accident, while reinstalling? Or is there another reason, why this does not work?

Comment: can you provide the link, you clicked? Also, are you sure, that you haved added page with the slug `projekti`?

Answer (score 0):

In [wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) it says:

```
   echo site_url();
```

will return the url for the current site you are on, but through parameters you can get url´s to other pages. The complete function is:

```
  site_url( $path, $scheme );
```

as an example they give:

```
  $url = site_url( '/secrets/', 'https' );
```

so maybe you want to try also using that second parameter "$scheme", so try:

```
  echo site_url('/projekti/', 'https);
```

or

```
  echo site_url('/projekti/', 'http');
```

Also if your site is called "page-projekti" you might want to try:

```
  echo site_url('/page-projekti/', 'https');
```

An other way to get a link to a page is, using the function:

```
 echo get_page_link($page_id);
```

Every page gets an id you can use. Here is a link, which explains how to get the id of a page: [WordPress Page ID](https://www.competethemes.com/blog/find-page-id/)

Comment: thank you for help but i still get the same message... i've tried both the 'get_page_link' and 'site_url'

Comment: does the "page-projekti" actually exist? like can you display the page in any other way?

Comment: yes it does exist. It also has a prefix 'page' so wordpress can read it as a page. I was able to fix the issue yeaterday by reinstalling the whole thing again and deleting my database... just doing it all from scratch. Nevertheless thank you for your time